# How to grab the string in $viewValue as the user is typing it in?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm new to Angular and am trying to create a typeahead input that displays only the results that start with what the user is typing. For example, in my plunker, when the user types 'n', all results with 'n' in them show up, not just the ones that begin with the letter.

I have been attempting to grab the $viewValue and compare it to list of results that can be shown to the user. 
I have also attempted just to see the current value in a bunch of ways, including {{$viewValue}}, etc, but have not correctly done so.

So ultimately, what is needed of me to be able to view and use (in some sort of compare method probably) the string that is entered into the typeahead input box?

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/totEvAhdQcrx3yONLX6p?p=preview

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container-fluid">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Centers loaded from local database"
        ng-model="selectedCenter"
        typeahead-min-length="2"
        typeahead="center as center.name for center in centers | filter:{state:$viewValue}"
        typeahead-template-url="typeahead-item.html" />
    <pre>{{selectedCenter | json}}</pre>
    input = {{$scope.viewValue}}
  </body>
```

Thank you for any insight that you can provide.

Comment: Why down vote with no reason why? If I need to edit something, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I initially misread the question (sorry about that) - you need to do a substring match to check whether a list item begins with the entered query, rather than *contains*. I've updated the code accordingly - we're now passing a custom function to the "filter" filter (see the arguments table in the docs). Here I'm just doing a simple substring match - this would actually show the whole list on a blank query if not for the ng-show. The custom function you use is executed and takes the array element as an argument - every item for which the fn returns "true" is included in the result.

---

As for displaying the list, this is a good candidate for Angular's ["filter" filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). If you need to trigger a function to make a server call to first populate the list, however, ng-change will work.

I've written up quick and dirty example to show what I'm talking about. ng-model for the search query, a filter, ng-show to hide the list when your query is empty, and ng-change to trigger a simple function that increments a "changes" counter. I'm using the filter directly into the view, but you can also use it in your code via the [$filter service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter).

**Note:** it's always a good idea to wrap any primitive on scope in an object so it plays nice with inheritance - in the example below I'm using "controller as" syntax to accomplish this, rather than just using ng-model="query". In this case, you can access the data from your controller via "this.query".

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.query = '';
  ctrl.list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'porcupine', 'gorilla', 'alpaca'];
  ctrl.changes = 0;

  this.beginsWith = function(val) {
    return (angular.lowercase(val.substr(0, ctrl.query.length)) 
           === angular.lowercase(ctrl.query));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">

  List is hidden by ng-show when query is empty so it only displays a match.
  <br>
  <b>Array:</b> {{main.list|json}}
  <br>
  <br>

  <input ng-change="main.changed()" type="text" ng-model="main.query">
  <label>Changes: {{main.changes}}</label>
  |
  <label>Current query text:</label><b>{{main.query}}</b>
  <ul>
    <li ng-show="main.query" ng-repeat="item in main.list|filter:main.beginsWith">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my plunker I have the list pretty well figured out, I now need to only show the user the results that begin with what they've typed into the typeahead input, not any results containing their input in the middle or the end. In your example, if I type just a, I would only want alpaca, but bar, baz, and gorilla are also displayed. Maybe the answer to this is within your post and it just went over my head? Thanks again.

Comment: Ah sorry, I think that was a reading comprehension fail on my part. If you take a look at the docs I link above to the ["filter" filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), the filter lets you pass in a function to do your own comparison rather than using their built-in behavior. The function is executed for each element in the collection, and gets passed that member as a param. Every element for which the function returns "true" is included in the results. I'll update my snippet accordingly.